# What does the "Mark set" message mean when going to the beginning or end of the buffer?

Tags: mark, navigation

Opening `emacs -Q`, then Pressing `Ctrl-Home` or `Ctrl-End` also shows this message.

`Mark set`

What is happening? Why is the mark set and is there a way not to set the mark?

Comment: Those two do not set the mark: `M-<` and `M->` (aka `beginning-of-buffer` and `end-of-buffer`) do set it. I don't know where you see `Mark set` after executing those two, but I certainly cannot reproduce it.

Comment: What @NickD said. Start from `emacs -Q` (no init file). Provide a step-by-step recipe. Trying to do that you'll discover your misunderstanding, I think. I think at this point your question (for yourself) should be "What am I doing that causes that message to be shown?"

Comment: Edited question to be slightly different from the original, with the issue happening from Ctrl Home/End instead of function calls.

Comment: Did you try `C-h c C-Home RET` to see what it is bound to? You would find that it is bound to `beginning-of-buffer` which *does* set the mark as pointed out already.

Comment: Reading your overall answers, I know you are able to read emacs elisp source code. Use `C-h k C-<home>` to see `beginning-of-buffer` is called. Then just look at th source of command `beginning-of-buffer` and indentify the `(push-mark)`. Why are you asking such a question?

Comment: When I asked this question, it wasn't obvious why "Mark set" was shown in the message output. I had to track down what caused the mark to be set, as it turns out `(goto-char (point-min/max))` are alternatives that don't set the mark. However I only knew this after looking into the code. Having checked the code again, while I can see that when `(consp arg)` is false, the mark wont be set, I still don't follow the underlying reasoning behind setting marks. If `beginning-of-buffer` is called indirectly, it may still be useful to suppress setting the mark, without having to use `cl-letf`.